# Protocolist: how to add 'secondary_target' to activities?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've recently discovered a new solution for activity feeds for rails. It is a Protocolist gem.
It is as simple as timeline_fu but supports some new useful features and hopefully will become much better in the future.

But currently I miss one of the timeline_fu features - it is an 'secondary_target' polymorphic assotiation.

For instance - there are Accounts in my app, each of which has many Notes

So, when Note is updated, Activity needs to be linked not only with note itself as a target, but also with an account it belongs to - it will be secondary_target.

Any suggestions how that can be done using Protocolist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the only way to do this is to use `fire` method inside a model or controller action

```
fire :updated, secontary_target: owner
```

This solution needs according fields to be added to Activity model manually.